# Display content during site maintenance

Tags: 6, caching, maintenance-mode

Is it possible to display a static version of a Drupal 6 website while it's in maintenance mode? Could something similar to [Boost](http://www.drupal.org/project/boost) help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Boost can do this actually. Here's a video that explains it: http://www.drupalove.com/drupal-video/how-can-boost-help-my-site

Pages which are set to static cache will remain running while in maintenance mode.